# How can i manage frontend assets with laravel mix and git?

Tags: laravel, git, assets, laravel-mix

I'm using Mix (this applies to Elixir as well i guess) to manage my frontend assets. I have Mix configured to version files in production but not in dev. As such, when i update assets, i get updated `app.js` and `app.css` files in dev and `app.{hash}.js` and `app.{hash}.css` files in production.

What is your advice on how to leverage this with version control?

1. Put the files in version control? If so how do i manage the constant changes during development? Keep adding new hashed files? Do i leave app.js and app.css on the production server?
2. `.gitignore` the js and css files and run npm on the production server to compile the assets locally?
3. Some other solution?

What are your thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

At my workplace we've .gitignore'd the css/js folders for almost a year for different projects with no issue just letting the server handle npm as part of it's build step.

And if you use yarn, it'll create a lock file which ensures you'll get the same exact js dependencies on production.

When using versioning just use the mix() helper on your script/css tags and it'll handle pointing to the correct file via the mix-manifest.json file in the public directory.

For example:

layout/app.blade.php has

`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

when you run npm mix creates the the public/mix-manifest.json file like so

`{ "/js/app.js": "/js/app.{hash-example}.js" }`

The only issue I've seen is with mix and using the `mix()` helper it appears to only work while `npm watch` is being run, which is something elixir handled fine before but mix is relatively new so it might get addressed, I myself haven't been annoyed enough to look into it since during development I always run `npm run hot` which does hot reloading on any js file changes. -- Edit: this appears to be fixed now

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. Wanted to know one thing, should `mix-manifest.json` be committed to git?

Comment: It can be but there isn't much point if you are `.gitignore`'ing the /js and /css folders. Just be aware it'll throw exception fast if it can't find the `mix-manifest.json` file and let that serve as a reminder to run npm. It always trips up some of our team members.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing exactly what you're doing with running mix() in production. I'm confused as to why laravel-mix is always put in as a dev-dependency within the package.json file, though.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite app.{hash}.js to app.js with nginx and add its to gitignore

Comment: My problem is not at webserver level it's on how to manage the files locally with git. My gut tells me compiling the assets in production is a bad idea but having to delete/add new files after compiling assets is a pita.